# Handle location and geocoding with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I want to get the current longitude and latitude of a location using Swift and display them.

If I update the scheme to have a default location then It just uses the default location the whole time and never updates with my current location, same when I try it on an actual device. Please Help.

```
struct prayer: Hashable {
var name: String
var time: String
var color: String 
}
```

LocationFetcher

```
class LocationFetcher: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let manager = CLLocationManager()
var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

override init() {
    super.init()
    manager.delegate = self
}


func start() {
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    location = locations.first?.coordinate
} }
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var prayers = [
    
    prayer(name: "Fajr", time: "", color: "Fajr"),
    prayer(name: "Sunrise", time: "", color: "Sunrise"),
    prayer(name: "Dhuhr", time: "", color: "Dhuhr"),
    prayer(name: "Asr", time: "", color: "Asr"),
    prayer(name: "Maghrib", time: "", color: "Maghrib"),
    prayer(name: "Isha", time: "", color: "Isha")
    
]

@State var date = ""
@State var currentSalah = ""
@State var nextSalah = ""
@State var country = ""

let locationManager = LocationFetcher()
    
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color("Background").ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack {
            Text(country)
                .padding([.top, .bottom], 20)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                .font(.title3)
            
            Text(currentSalah)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .fontWeight(.light)
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                .font(.title)
            
            Text(nextSalah)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
            
            Text(date)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .fontWeight(.light)
            ForEach(prayers, id: \.self) { prayer in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "deskclock.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(Color(prayer.color))
                    Text(prayer.name)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(prayer.color))
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Text(prayer.time)
                        
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(Color(prayer.color))
                    
                }
                .padding(.all, 10)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        locationManager.start()
        getPrayerTime()
        
    }
}

func getPrayerTime() {
    let cal = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    let date = cal.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
    let coordinates = Coordinates(latitude: locationManager.location?.latitude ?? 33.3152, longitude: locationManager.location?.longitude ?? 44.3661)
    
    var params = CalculationMethod.ummAlQura.params
    params.madhab = .hanafi
    
    if let prayers = PrayerTimes(coordinates: coordinates, date: date, calculationParameters: params) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")!
        
        self.prayers[0].time = formatter.string(from: prayers.fajr)
        self.prayers[1].time = formatter.string(from: prayers.sunrise)
        self.prayers[2].time = formatter.string(from: prayers.dhuhr)
        self.prayers[3].time = formatter.string(from: prayers.asr)
        self.prayers[4].time = formatter.string(from: prayers.maghrib)
        self.prayers[5].time = formatter.string(from: prayers.isha)
        
        self.updateDate()
        self.updateLocationName()
        self.updateLabel(prayerTimes: prayers)
        
    }
}

func updateDate() {
    let hijriCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamicCivil)
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
    formatter.calendar = hijriCalendar
    formatter.dateFormat = "-------- EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy -------- "
    
    date = "\(formatter.string(from: Date()))"
}

func updateLabel(prayerTimes: PrayerTimes) {
    
    guard let current = prayerTimes.currentPrayer() else { return }
    currentSalah = "Time For \(current)"
    
    guard let next = prayerTimes.nextPrayer() else { return }
    let countdown = prayerTimes.time(for: next)
    let diffTime = countdown.timeIntervalSince(Date())
    
    let diffTimeMin = diffTime / 60
    let diffTimeMinRem = Int(diffTimeMin.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
    let diffTimeHour = Int(diffTimeMin / 60)
    let stringDiff = "\(next) is in \(diffTimeHour) hr, \(diffTimeMinRem) min"

    print(nextSalah = stringDiff)
    
}

func updateLocationName() {
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: locationManager.location?.latitude ?? 33.3152, longitude: locationManager.location?.longitude ?? 44.3661)
    
    
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        
        guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else { return }
        
        country = placemark.country ?? ""
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
 class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    @Published var longitudeStorage : Double = 0.0
    @Published var latitudeStorage : Double = 0.0
    @Published var isTrue : Bool = false
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  40, longitude: 120), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 100, longitudeDelta: 100))
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func requestAllowOnceLocationPermission()  {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let latestLocation = locations.first else{
            //Show an error
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: latestLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.015, longitudeDelta: 0.015))
            //check region value
            print(self.region.center.longitude)
            self.longitudeStorage = Double(self.region.center.longitude)
            self.latitudeStorage = Double(self.region.center.latitude)
            print("Longitude --> \(self.longitudeStorage)")
            print("Latitude --> \(self.latitudeStorage)")

            
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I'm making a variable that will store the longitude and latitude that you get